# Why do my OpenVPN iptables rules cause a port forward to hang?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, openvpn, iptables

I have a VPS running an OpenVPN Access Server and a Raspberry Pi running an OpenVPN Client. The client is connected to the server, and I would like to access the client via SSH through the server. Thus, I forward port 667 on the server to port 22 on the client with the following two rules:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING 1 -d {WAN-IP} -p tcp --dport 667 -j DNAT --to-dest 172.27.200.2:22
sudo iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -d 172.27.200.2 -p tcp --dport 667 -j SNAT --to-source {WAN-IP}
```

However, the connection attempt hangs. tcpdump shows that the [S] packets are coming in from the source initiating the connection, but there is no response on the end of the server – not even a "connection refused". I also cannot ping the server's VPN-IP from the client. Clearing the server's existing iptables rules and then applying the new ones fixes this, but breaks the functionality of the VPN, rendering the client unable to access the internet.

These are the iptables rules which cause the connection to hang. What would be the way to fix this without breaking the functionality of the VPN?

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             {WANIP}              tcp dpt:667 to:172.27.200.2:22
AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             172.27.200.2         tcp dpt:667 to:172.27.232.1
AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
AS0_NAT_PRE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x2000000/0x2000000

Chain AS0_NAT (3 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             to:{WAN-IP}
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_NAT_PRE (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
AS0_NAT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x8000000/0x8000000
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  anywhere             169.254.0.0/16      
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16      
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12       
AS0_NAT_TEST  all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8          
AS0_NAT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain AS0_NAT_TEST (4 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             mark match 0x4000000/0x4000000
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             172.27.200.0/24     
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             172.27.224.0/20     
AS0_NAT    all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

*KEY: VPS WAN-IP = {WANIP}, VPS VPN-IP = 172.27.232.1, Client VPN-IP = 172.27.200.2*

EDIT: Here are the results of iptables-save.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Aug  2 05:18:22 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3503:176762]
:INPUT ACCEPT [9309:2594148]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [16:920]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8990:4483087]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [8994:4483331]
:AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_MANGLE_TUN - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST
-A PREROUTING -i as0t+ -j AS0_MANGLE_TUN
-A AS0_MANGLE_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2000000/0xffffffff
-A AS0_MANGLE_TUN -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug  2 05:18:22 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Aug  2 05:18:22 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [3179:157338]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1:52]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8988:4482919]
:AS0_ACCEPT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_IN_ROUTE - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_LOCAL - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_POST - [0:0]
:AS0_OUT_S2C - [0:0]
:AS0_WEBACCEPT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j AS0_ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j AS0_ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 1194 -j AS0_ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 943 -j AS0_WEBACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_IN_PRE
-A FORWARD -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_S2C
-A OUTPUT -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT_LOCAL
-A AS0_ACCEPT -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_IN -d 172.27.224.1/32 -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_IN -j AS0_IN_POST
-A AS0_IN_NAT -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000000/0x8000000
-A AS0_IN_NAT -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_IN_POST -d 172.27.200.2/32 -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_IN_POST -o as0t+ -j AS0_OUT
-A AS0_IN_POST -j DROP
-A AS0_IN_PRE -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j AS0_IN
-A AS0_IN_PRE -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j AS0_IN
-A AS0_IN_PRE -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j AS0_IN
-A AS0_IN_PRE -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j AS0_IN
-A AS0_IN_PRE -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000000/0x4000000
-A AS0_IN_ROUTE -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_OUT -j AS0_OUT_POST
-A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 5 -j DROP
-A AS0_OUT_LOCAL -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_OUT_POST -j DROP
-A AS0_OUT_S2C -j AS0_OUT
-A AS0_WEBACCEPT -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug  2 05:18:22 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Tue Aug  2 05:18:22 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [3273:165446]
:INPUT ACCEPT [3268:165034]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [224:15606]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [225:15658]
:AS0_NAT - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST - [0:0]
:AS0_NAT_TEST - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d {WAN-IP}/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 667 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.200.2:22
-A PREROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST
-A POSTROUTING -d 172.27.200.2/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 667 -j SNAT --to-source {WAN-IP}
-A POSTROUTING -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST
-A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 0x2000000/0x2000000 -j AS0_NAT_PRE
-A AS0_NAT -o ens3 -j SNAT --to-source {WAN-IP}
-A AS0_NAT -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_POST_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_PRE -m mark --mark 0x8000000/0x8000000 -j AS0_NAT
-A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 169.254.0.0/16 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
-A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
-A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 172.16.0.0/12 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
-A AS0_NAT_PRE -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j AS0_NAT_TEST
-A AS0_NAT_PRE -j AS0_NAT
-A AS0_NAT_PRE_REL_EST -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_TEST -o as0t+ -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_TEST -m mark --mark 0x4000000/0x4000000 -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_TEST -d 172.27.200.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_TEST -d 172.27.224.0/20 -j ACCEPT
-A AS0_NAT_TEST -j AS0_NAT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug  2 05:18:22 2022
```

EDIT2: I got it to work using the three rules indicated in this post on a completely reset, unmodified server instance: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449853/port-forwarding-using-openvpn-client

Comment: Paste `iptables-save` instead.

Comment: @TomYan I have added the printout.

Comment: What subnet mask / prefix length are you using on the server and the client for their VPN IP? Any particular reason for using `172.27.232.1` on the server instead of `172.27.200.1`? Does the default route of the server lead to the VPN tunnel (i.e. "`redirect-gateway`" or equivalent)?

Comment: Assuming the SNAT rule is actually needed (because the server isn't the "default gateway" of the client), it should has `--dport 22` and `--to-source {VPS VPN-IP}` instead.

Comment: @TomYan I changed the subnet to 172.27.232.0/24 for the clients' static ips, but it still does not work. I am not sure if the default route leads to the VPN tunnel. How would I find that out? 

Lastly, the SNAT rule seems to be unnecessary. When I omit it after flushing the iptables, the single DNAT rule works – aside from not functioning as a VPN.

Comment: `How would I find that out?` Depends on the client OS. If it's Linux you can check `ip r`. And you can check server and client conf anyway. `the single DNAT rule works – aside from not functioning as a VPN` No idea what you mean. Until you see replies from the client coming back to the server, you can't really tell what "works" or if the rule is necessary.

Comment: @TomYan With regards to the single DNAT working, I mean that I can SSH into my Raspberry Pi through my VPS's WAN-IP. However, my Raspberry Pi cannot access the internet (e.g. ping google.com).

Comment: What about `ping 8.8.8.8`? Also if you `ip a` on the server, is the interface that is configured with WAN IP named `ens3`?

Comment: @TomYan `ip a` does show that the WAN IP interface is ens3. When I flush the iptables, `ping 8.8.8.8` on the client does not work.

Comment: And what's the name of the VPN interface? I looked into your firewall rules and it seems like the only explanation is that the name doesn't start with `as0t`, otherwise you should have opposite result (i.e. you can't ssh into the Pi via the VPS from another non-VPN-client host but the Pi should be able to reach the Internet "actively"). Although you haven't been clear on what host are you doing it from regarding `I can SSH into my Raspberry Pi through my VPS's WAN-IP`.

Comment: From my host PC, I can ssh as _user@WANIP:667_. My VPS interfaces: `lo: 127.0.0.1/8, ens3: {WANIP}/32, as0t0: 172.27.224.1/25, as0t1: 172.27.224.129/25` My client interfaces: `lo: 127.0.0.1/8, wlan0: 192.168.1.9/24, tun0: 172.27.232.2/24`

Comment: What exactly did you mean by `When I flush the iptables`? Do you mean like you emptied it / have all the rules you pasted above removed?

Comment: `iptables -F && iptables -t nat -F && iptables -t mangle -F && iptables -X`

Comment: No wonder. Of course it won't work. You'll at least need a `SNAT` / `MASQUERADE` rule for traffics from the VPN interface(s) to `ens3`. I suppose you want to start / test from scratch, but make sure you still add something like `-t nat -A POSTROUTING -o ens3 -j MASQUERADE` (or `-j SNAT --to-source {WANIP}` if you like) back.

Comment: That didn't work. Both with and without the iptables rules flushed. When flushed, the client cannot connect to the internet. When not, the connection to the client times out.

Comment: Have you set the `ip_forward` sysctl to `1`?

Comment: Wait a minute. Your server and client IP subnets don't correspond to each other, according to your last comment. Do *you* have any idea what `as0t0` and `as0t1` are exactly? Are you having two VPN server instances? Why is your configuration like a complete mess (as if you have no idea what you are doing and you just keep making *random* changes).

Comment: I am a complete novice to this, and my attempts thus far have been very haphazard. I understand that as0t0 is a network interface for the OpenVPN daemon subnet. I reset the server and it is back to 172.27.224.1/21 as0t0 and 172.27.232.1/21 as0t1. I have only one VPN instance running. ip_forward is set to 1.

Comment: On a clean access server instance, I got it to work. Thank you for your patience with my guessing and your continued assistance. I appreciate it very much.